# Does using the Threadpool in .net break the (loosely speaking) rules if using an IOC container?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control

I like the Inversion of Control (IOC) pattern and use it a lot. As usual I have my problems with threads and where they sit in the OO ecosphere of .NET.

I was thinking about threading and using the "built-in" Threadpool Class in .Net, and realised that it operates on a whole different level to your code and that it was outside of the scope of the IOC pattern with regards to IOC containers such as Unity.

I don't know a heck of a lot of where a Thread would exist in the realms of IOC, but if can be treated as a class then it could be a candidate for inclusion into your IOC framework. If this be the case, how do you deal with use of the ThreadPool.

Would this assessment be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I actually never use the `ThreadPool` directly, but have an interface `IThreadPoolService` which I resolve via an IoC container. This is very helpful for unit testing logic where the threading aspect would make things more difficult but add nothing to the testing aspect. I can mock out the service with a non-threaded test version.

I don't feel that using the `ThreadPool` violates IoC as the `ThreadPool` is not actually controlling tasks per se, it's only responsible for calling the entry point. It's also not "creational" which is a core aspect of an IoC container.

Using an IoC container to resolve an `IThreadPoolService` gives you the usual benefits of adding a layer of indirection e.g. you can change implementations and add additional behaviours such as logging which of course can be supported via IoC\DI.

Comment: I like the style of using the interface for the Threadpool. What you do then make a pointer to the Threadpool in the container via the interface, or Roll your own Threadpool?

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers For the real thread-pool I have a proxy type pattern where I have a class that implements `IThreadPoolService` and forwards calls to the real `ThreadPool` - it's a simple wrapper. I register this when bootstrapping my container at application startup, then all requests to resolve the interface will get the `ThreadPool` proxy class. For testing scenarios I can supply a dummy implementation of `IThreadPoolService` which does not actually use threads, but calls the passed in delegates directly.

Comment: @chibacity Not sure I agree with the fact that testing the threading itself has no value; difficult to test yes but it still has value. Threading bugs are evil to track down.

Comment: @Aaron I did not mean to appear to say that testing multi-threaded code has no value. That's not what I was trying to convey at all. Sometimes you need to test logic that is orthogonal to the threading aspect e.g. with asynchronous code. In these situations it is helpful to suspend the threading aspects so you can more easily test the behaviour. I do test multi-threaded code - I hear you loud and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Threading and IoC don't have much in common. The loose coupling can take place regardless of threading being involved. Attempting to provide an interface for the Thread class is possible however you don't abstract away the other .NET framework classes do you?

Take a service which will expose data in some form. If the service decides to provide async behavior via threading the consumer will have to take this into account. Making a call to the service would still be within the realm of IoC.

With the service being exposed as an interface it can get changed out as needed while still providing the desired behavior which in this case would be async behavior. This would allow you to define a method in the interface and a callback/event once the data is ready all while still making use of Unity and other IoC frameworks.

Comment: I agree that Thread Class and IOC have nothing in Common, but the Threadpool and an IOC that implements a ThreadPool Model of its own would I presume have a conflict of interest.

Comment: @WenNeedAnswers Not sure that I see it that way. The ThreadPool is nothing more then a portion of the framework. This goes back to asking about how you treat other portions of the framework? Do you have an IString? Of course not. Providing a service which leverages the ThreadPool is understandable but how the ThreadPool in any way ties into IoC concepts more then any other structure doesn't necessarily jive IMHO.

Comment: The built in Configuration classes and all the other myriad of static typed classes would be fine too, such as File etc. IMHO I would think that this would be bad code and would smell a bit. I think in the same way, using the ThreadPool is not being explicit and would mean that you couldn't replace it with something better/equal which is another of the advocacies of IOC.